# SOAP client only works in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, soap

I have made a SOAP client in javascript. The problem is that it only works with Google Chrome.

The code:

```
$("#send").click(function (event) {
    var wsUrl = "http://myip:8084/Service1.asmx";
    var soapRequest =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
            <soap:Body> \
                <GetVozilo xmlns="http://mydomain.com/apps"> \
                      <vin>' + $("#vin").val() + '</vin> \
                </GetVozilo> \
            </soap:Body> \
        </soap:Envelope>';

        console.log(soapRequest);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: wsUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: processSuccess,
                    error: processError
                });

            });
```

In console I also get this error:

> OPTIONS http://mydomain.com/Service1.asmx 403 (Forbidden)

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get data from different domain in any browser. In jQuery you can use JSONP. 
More at: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/same-origin-policy/

Answer (score 0):

sounds very much like this is because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

you can't send ajax-requets to another domain (in your case `localhost` vs `84.255.246.99:8084`) than he one the script is executed on. i assume you added some kind of exception regulation to chrome so it works for you in that browser.

to check this, use firebug or the develover console of a non-working browser to inspect the response-headers - you might find something like this:

```
X-Frame-Options:sameorigin
```